# Datanucleus + Postgres 9.3 + Amazon RDS failure

Tags: java, postgresql, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, datanucleus, amazon-rds

The title almost says it all.

I'm developing a `Java` web app, hosted in `Elastic Beanstalk` using `Datanucleus 4.0.6` to communicate to a `postgresql 9.3` database. The database is hosted in `Amazon RDS`.

I've tried every combination of settings I can think of:

- Getting beanstalk to create the DB
- Manually creating a private DB
- Manually creating a public DB
- Assigning public/private DBs to all available `VPCs`
- Using postgres 9.4 instead of 9.3

No matter what I do, I get the following error message when trying to start communication with the DB.

```
 No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://myvalidurl.com:5432/ebdb
```

I get the same error if I make `myvalidurl` most definitely invalid, so I cannot tell if I simply cannot "see" the DB, or if the port is closed or if somehow it just isn't speaking the expected type of postgres.

Finally, I can run this with a local db and everything is ok.

Does anyone have any idea what I might have missed when configuring `Elastic Beanstalk` to talk to `RDS`?

Comment: why not just write a couple of lines of JDBC code, load the driver and try to access the URL and see what exception JDBC throws, inc stack trace?

Comment: I just tried that and it worked... which makes the JDO failure all the more confusing.

Comment: so look at the stack trace that was thrown and compare with what you're doing ... is there a difference? JDO likely uses connection pooling for one thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the default `Tomcat 8` installation from `Elastic Beanstalk` includes `commons-pools` and `dbcp`. `Datanucleus` was using the `dbcp` implementation to connect to the database and for whatever reason the full `jdbc` URI isn't passed all the way down the chain of calls.

I'm sure this is some kind of `persistence.xml` type configuration problem, but for my purposes the solution was simply:

```
<property name="datanucleus.connectionPoolingType" value="None"/>
```

Comment: I think DataNucleus, by default, will use a builtin DBCP actually, not some other dbcp jar in the CLASSPATH. But then you still have the option of using any of the other connection pools

Answer (score 1):

This kind of error happens when the postgre-jdbc.jar is in your.war#WEB-APP/lib/ folder. Remove it from there and put it in $CATALINA_HOME/lib/ folder and it will work fine.

The problem is in the classloader used by DriverManager class.

Comment: This wasn't the issue.